# Show that $T: X \to Y $ is a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T: X \to Y$ be a linear operator where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $\mathcal F$ be a subset of  $Y^*$ that separates the points of $Y$. Given that $f(T(x_n))\to  0$ whenever $f$ is in $\mathcal F$ and $||x_n|| \to 0$. Show that $T$ is bounded.

### My work:

I was trying to solve this using the definition of a operator, 
$$i.e.,\, ||T|| = sup\{ ||Tx|| : ||x||=1 \}$$
but I failed.Need some help.

Comment: Can you please tell me that how these are related to the question? @Martin-Blas Perez Pinilla

Comment: Sorry, I've misread the question.

Comment: @Saikat use close graph theoem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538307/show-that-t-x-to-y-is-a-bounded-linear-operator#comment3132463_1538307), we show that the graph of $T$ is closed. Assume that $(x_n , T(x_n) ) \to (x, y)$. Then $x_n - x \to 0$. From the assumption, for all $f\in \mathcal F$, 
$$f(T(x_n -x)) \to 0 \Rightarrow f(T(x_n)) \to f(T(x)).$$
On the other hand, for all $f\in Y^*$ we have 
$$ T(x_n) \to y \Rightarrow f(T(x_n)) \to f(y).$$
That is, 
$$f(T(x)) = f(y)$$
for all $f\in \mathcal F$. By assumption of $\mathcal F$, $T(x)  =y$, so the graph of $T$ is closed and so $T$ is bounded by the closed graph theorem.